# Squash commits on GitHub without command-line interface

Tags: github, squash, git-squash

How can I squash my last X commits together into one commit using **GitHub**, online with just a browser, without downloading/installing/configuring git, cloning the repo, using command-line tools to [do it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git), and then committing and pushing back up to GitHub?

Comment: Github is not a superset of Git's CLI functionality, there are many *many* things you require a real Git client to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible. You can consider using a GUI tool to do the squash, but that'll still require you to pull the repo locally and install a GUI tool locally.